# RXJava execute more observables sequentially

Tags: java, android, rx-java

**I'm using Firebase to get objects a real time, I would like to execute  more observables sequentially (first in first out), thanks
you!**

```java
public void getDispatch(Dispatch dispatch) {
    Single<DispatchAction> observable =  Single.just(dispatch)
    .map(order1 -> {
        return convertDispatch(order1);
    });

   DisposableSingleObserver<DispatchAction> actionDisposableObserver =
             new DisposableSingleObserver<DispatchAction>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DispatchAction action) {//Process result }

        public void onError(Throwable e) {//Error }
   };

   compositeDisposable.add(
        observable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(actionDisposableObserver)
   );
}
```

Comment: You can use concat operator. Observable.concat(request1, request2).

Comment: yes, but If I don't know how many objects/request I have. Firebase emits asynchronously.

Comment: How do you get data out of Firebase and how do you make observables you want to do sequentially? If you have an outer Observable, you can use `concatMap` to do sequential sub-Observables.

Comment: Firebase can emit elements at the same time, I don't know the number, for example it can emit now 3 elements and in a few minutes another 10, I want these to be executed sequentially because they create concurrency, the "concat" operator works if I know how many observables I have "concat ( request1, request2) "but in my case it is not possible.